# AWS instance crashes after I run a build job on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, instance

The build job shows that it's running, but it will eventually crash ('eventually' because I have created different instances, and they end up crashing when I want to deploy the application). After it becomes unresponsive, I'm not able to login to the EC2 instance anymore. I get the following error: "port 22: Operation timed out". I'm using the free tier linux and t2.micro instance type. I tried restarting the instance, but it's still unresponsive.

Does this happen to anybody else?

Comment: can you try stop and start instead of reboot

Comment: I tried that too, but no luck. I think the problem is the CPU power. The free tier only has 1vCPU and 1GB of memory causing it to crash after a second build.